# MVC3 asp.net error: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: items on dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I am getting a dump ONLY in the server and not in my local system when trying to post the data. There is a page which submits some value to the database. I have also modeled the dropdown in the page as mandatory. However, when clicking on "Create", instead of giving an error like "Missing"; it throws a dump.

Dump trace:

```
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: items

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: items

Source Error: 


Line 65:         </div>
Line 66:         <div class="editor-field">
Line 67:             @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ProjectName, new SelectList(Model.ProjectDetail, "ProjectName", "ProjectName"),"")
Line 68:             <span runat="server" style="color:Red;" visible="false"> *</span>
Line 69:             @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProjectName)

Source File: d:\hosting\11178048\html\fbpm\fbpm\Views\User\Create.cshtml    Line: 67
```

Stack Trace:

```
[ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: items]   System.Web.Mvc.MultiSelectList..ctor(IEnumerable items, String dataValueField, String dataTextField, IEnumerable selectedValues)
+289714    System.Web.Mvc.SelectList..ctor(IEnumerable items, String dataValueField, String dataTextField) +19    ASP._Page_Views_User_Create_cshtml.Execute() in d:\hosting\11178048\html\fbpm\fbpm\Views\User\Create.cshtml:67    System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +197    System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +81    System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.RunPage() +17
```

The Controller code:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    var model = new UserDetail
    {
        ProjectDetail = db1.ProjectDetails.ToList()
    };
    return View(model);
} 

//
// POST: /User/Create

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(UserDetail userdetail)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.UserDetails.Add(userdetail);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("SearchCust");  
    }

    return View(userdetail);
}
```

The view code:

```
@model fbpm.Models.UserDetail

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create Customer";
}

<h2>Create Customer</h2>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Customer Detail</legend>
        <div id ="left" style="float:left; width:400px;">
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserID)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserID)
            <span runat="server" style="color:Red;" visible="false"> *</span>
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserID)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password)
            <span runat="server" style="color:Red;" visible="false"> *</span>
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PANNo)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PANNo)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PANNo)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmailID)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EmailID)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmailID)
        </div>
        <br />
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create Customer" />
        </p>

        </div>
        <div id = "left3" style="float:left; width:400px">
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProjectName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ProjectName, new SelectList(Model.ProjectDetail, "ProjectName", "ProjectName"),"")
            <span runat="server" style="color:Red;" visible="false"> *</span>
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProjectName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BookedDate)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.BookedDate)
            <span runat="server" style="color:Red;" visible="false"> *</span>
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BookedDate)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BookedAmount)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.BookedAmount)
            <span runat="server" style="color:Red;" visible="false"> *</span>
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BookedAmount)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Contact1)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Contact1)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Contact1)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Contact2)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Contact2)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Contact2)
        </div>
        </div>
        <div id="left1" style="float:left; width:400px;">
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Role, new { @readonly = "readonly", @Value = "400" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Role)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FullAddress)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.FullAddress)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FullAddress)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.State)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.State)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.State)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Country)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Country)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Country)
        </div>


        </div>

    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "SearchCust")
</div>
```

I have searched a lot in the net and found that adding a viewbag for the project name in the submit action before returning the view owuld help; but, it didnt. Please can someone help?

Regards

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I'm assuming you only see this exception when your insert fails; you then try to reuse the `UserDetail` model in the view for the same page.

The error you are seeing is due to the nature of working with HTTP - anything that is not directly bound to an input is **not** retained. So, when you attempt to rebuild the view, the list you are trying to bind the drop-down helper to is null, since `UserDetail.ProjectDetail` has not been repopulated. You can fix this like so:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(UserDetail userdetail)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.UserDetails.Add(userdetail);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("SearchCust");  
    }

    userdetail.ProjectDetail = db1.ProjectDetails.ToList();

    return View(userdetail);
}
```

Comment: De nada. If you're new to MVC, you might find the NerdDinner tutorial useful: http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/Section/id-321793.html. Otherwise, this is the best book I've found: http://www.amazon.com/Pro-ASP-NET-MVC-Adam-Freeman/dp/1430242361.

Comment: Its working. Error was kinda missleading because it was thrown on adding first validation error in my custom DTO validator, which has nothing to do with selectlist control.

Comment: Exactly what I needed.  Spent hours on this you saved me several more. Thanks! +1

Comment: @stom Not entirely sure what you're asking, but regardless of the form method, the only values sent to the server when the form is submitted are those bound to a form element, like input, textarea, or select.

Comment: @stom The modelbinder takes those values and attempts to match them up to properties in the model class, if a model is used in the action declaration.

Comment: hi , i mean in the question `ProjectName` property is not populated in POST and thus gives Exception, but in GET its populated.

Comment: @stom If I understand what you're asking, then yes. In the initial page load (the GET action), the ProjectName property gets populated. Those values are not carried through to the POST action (when the form is submitted) since they are not bound to a form element.

Comment: thank you, ok will  NerdDinner tutorial help me to learn mvc 4 ? because it is in mvc 2 and uses visual studio 10, i also want to learn view models list etc in DB first method, so which books will help ?

Comment: @stom The latest version seems to be MVC4 (http://nerddinner.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#mvc4/), but the process doesn't change much. Aside from switching to Razor, most of the differences are probably cosmetic. Otherwise, the Amazon link I also provided is for a MVC4 version of a fairly decent Apress book on the subject. The eBook version is a little cheaper: http://www.apress.com/9781430242369

Comment: Thank you! This was driving absolutely crazy until I found your answer.

Answer (score 2):

I noticed that create button is a submit button

So it must call action with HttpPost attribute
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(UserDetail userdetail)

In this action, it returns View(userdetail);

But this userdetail object is created by model binder from the submit data from browser.
So it won't have values in ProjectDetail property.

You can step it through

Comment: you mean, i can just return View() instead of view(usedetail)?

Comment: I mean you need to put a break point in [HttpPost] public ActionResult Create(UserDetail userdetail) to check if it has value for ProjectDetail. If not, you should reload ProjectDetail in that action.

Comment: Ok. Actually, the dump occurs only in the server. Can you please tell me how I can reload it in this action?

Comment: just use  ProjectDetail = db1.ProjectDetails.ToList()